# Set selected folder in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm using the following code to set the currently selected folder in outlook

```
  OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk;
```

There seems to be a type mismatch

***Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder'***

I have tried

```
 OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk;
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a property of type `MAPIFolder` (which is a COM object) to a value of type `OlDefaultFolders` (which is an int). You probably missed a call to `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`:

```
 OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = OutlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);
```